# How to change plugin`s template (view) correctly?

Tags: widgets, templates

I'm new to WordPress. So, I have installed a plugin to display recent posts (that's it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/flexible-posts-widget/). This plugin have a widget. And now I want to change widget's template for my needs. I found it in **plugin_folder/views/default.php**. As I know, it is bad practice to edit files directly in plugin folder. So, how can I copy this file to work with him in my own theme?.

Comment: Do you even need the plugin to view recent posts? It should be quite simple to add that functionality into the theme yourself without a plugin.

Comment: May be. Anyway, I don't know how to show posts from Custom Post Types without plugin. Standard widget called "Recent Posts" does not show it. The fact is that my WP experience - 1 week, so it's no wonder that I don't know very simple things.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little code snippet to get you started. This will query through the most recent custom post types named "custom_post_type". Change this value to the name of the custom post you wish to query.

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type', // <-- make sure to use the name of your custom post type here
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        echo "<h1>" . get_the_title() . "</h1>";

    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

No plugin needed. If you wish to do some extra reading on custom queries for posts you can use the Wordpress Codex site as a reference. Here is the WP_Query page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query